# How many savings can be achieved?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a problem. I have a dataframe, this gives me the savings. If I sum this up I get all the savings of X data points.

Last year I had Y data points. I would now predict / extrapolate how much savings I can expect.

Thus I have to calculate the following

```
(all savings / data points) * number of old data points = extrapolated savings
```

In my estimation, this is wrong. So how could I calculate an extrapolation for the savings of the 10 data points?

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'saveing': [10, 20, 30, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
count_datapoints = 10
(df['saveing'].sum() / df.shape[0]) * count_datapoints
[OUT] 162.5
```

Dataframe

```
   id  saveing
0   1       10
1   2       20
2   3       30
3   4        5
```

Comment: It would help for future question if the people who vote the question down also comment ;)

Comment: What's wrong? Your code seems to calculate what it's intended to...